# Stop divs from moving vertically on resize

Tags: html, css

I was just trying out Xara Web Designer, and created a page:
http://goo.gl/SFSmn

When the page is zoomed in or out, the position of the main `div.xr_ap` moves up and down, I've tried numerous fixes, like auto margin alignment, absolute positioning, tabling, but none seem to give a desirable result! :-(

If possible, would anyone know how to keep the div in place at all levels of zoom with CSS? (similar to how the slider above behaves!)

Thank you, all responses greatly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove margin-top from here `div.xr_ap`

```
div.xr_ap {
    margin-top: 45px;
}
```

Replace this above class with mentioned below css

**CSS**

```
div.xr_ap {
    position: relative;
    top: -535px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, Shailender! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `div#wrapper` changes its height based on the page width but the `div.xr_ap` is aligned with the top of the `div#wrapper` when it should be aligned with its bottom.

Remove `div.xr_ap` `top` (so it is positioned after the preceding element' `div#wrapper`) and move its elements upwards (or give up absolute positioning absolutely, order the images left-to-right, top-to-bottom and let them flow by removing their position attributes).

If the designer only supports absolute positioning, you have to set a fixed width to the `div#wrapper` to prevent it from resizing.

I have no experience with the web designer, so correct me if i'm suggesting something the designer does not allow.

Comment: Thank you, Jan :-) the designer does not support this, but I tried your suggestion manually, and it worked! Though I went for Shailender's approach, as it's a much shorter solution. Once again, Thank you! :-)